# Enforce label text within extent of an atlas composer

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I am using QGIS (2.8) and the wonderful Atlas composer, and what I would like to be able to do, is stop labels from being 'cropped' by the atlas generator (Example below). [image: Example of text cropping off edge of map]

I know this goes against the purpose of an atlas creation ( in that there should be overlap so you can navigate from one map to the next), but is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: If you like the atlas composer in QGIS 2.8, you'll love the many new features available in 2.18. Basically every style setting can be set using data-defined override. Using variables like @atlas_feature, any style setting can be dependent on which page of the atlas it's on.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use `wordwrap()` in labeling the field and increase the number of lines to three instead of two. You can use `wordwrap()` as follows:

```
 wordwrap(  "Fieldname" ,number)         # example:  wordwrap(  "Name_2" ,5)
```

where:

`Fieldname` is the name of the target field, and `Number` is the desired length of characters to wrap the string

[image]

You should place it under `Label with` as in the following image:

[image]

Another solution is to uncheck `Show Partial label` from the labeled layer by going to the Layer Properties -> Click on the icon at the upper right :

[image]

Uncheck `Show Partial label`.

[image]

I am afraid it will remove completely the label which is partially rendered, but you can give it a try, it may solve the problem.